# passing const char** to function - how to build char**?

Tags: c, matlab, redis

I am trying to build a matlab wrapper to hiredis. I never do any C programming and I always run into trouble because I cannot remember the basics. Because I am processing the args coming from matlab, which need to be converted from mxArray objects to `char*`, I need to use the function

void *redisCommandArgv(redisContext *c, int argc, const char **argv, const size_t *argvlen);

I understand the gist but the thing hanging me up is what is argv defined as `const char**`? Why not just `char*`? I don't know how to build `char**` in this case. If it were `char*` I would just loop through my mxArrays and realloc each time and add to the master char*.

edit- I know what `char*` is, I know what const is. What I cannot remember or find by googling is how to construct a bunch of `char*` of different lengths into `char**`.

Comment: "I never do any C programming and I always run into trouble because I cannot remember the basics" - that's pretty much a barrier to writing C code...

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in the library, it should be `const char* const* argv` since the function does not modify it.  And then you could pass a `char**` without difficulty.

Answer (score 2):

> What I cannot remember or find by googling is how to construct a bunch
>   of char* of different lengths into char**

Here is a way if you know ahead of time what you want the strings to be:

```
const char* my_string_array[] = {"hi", "world"};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `char **` is a pointer-to an array of character pointers (i.e. strings). In simple words you need to pass an array of strings to the `redisCommandArgv` function and argc is the size of this array.

`const char*` keyword indicates that the function is not going to make any changes to the data pointed by this pointer i.e the string. `const char**` is an array of such `const char *` pointers.

Comment: Nope, the `const` keyword indicates the the array can only contain pointers to constant strings.  But the array can still be modified.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, if it were ambiguous let me re-word it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what `const char **` *typically* refers to. `const char *` *usually* refers to a string, and `const char **` *usually* refers to an array of strings. When the argument in question is `argv` you can count on it expecting an array of strings.

A way to understand why `char *` is a string is that a string is just an array of characters, null terminated in the case of C-strings, which this most definitely is expecting. The `const` part is just a guarantee that it won't be modified by the function in question, which is a good thing.